# How can I fix old duplicates closed under the old system?

Tags: support, specific-question, dupehammer

Prompted by [Mutable Default Method Arguments In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039191)

It is currently marked as a duplicate of [Why do mutable default arguments remember mutations between function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/). This was done under the old system, such that the info box at the top of the question looks different from the current style, and the (old) question title is hard-coded. I have a gold badge in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), but I cannot edit the duplicate links because the old system simply doesn't have that functionality.

There is a newer, high-quality question that is a much more specific duplicate for the question: [Why does Pycharm warn about mutable default arguments? How can I work around them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686829)

How can I re-link to the better duplicate? If I reopen the question, will I be able to dupe-hammer it again? If I do so, will it use the new system? I don't want to risk making destructive changes that I can't easily revert.

Comment: You can definitely use your hammer to reopen and instantly close it as a duplicate (assuming you haven't successfully voted to close it before). And yes, it will use the new system at that point.

Comment: What about the case where I *was* involved in voting to close (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838255, which I think is better linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676729/) ?

Comment: meh, if you have the tools to fix it, and aren't acting in a situation where you stand to benefit from it, I don't see the harm. If you will benefit, maybe get another's opinion.

Comment: @KevinB I mean, on a technical level. I don't think it will allow me to re-close the question unilaterally at that point.

Comment: You'll be able to reopen it, but not close it, in that case. For odd cases like this, you can ask for help in SOCVR (there are often hammers of various stripes floating around there). You should confirm that it's ok to ask for help with these, as it's an old question and you've participated in closing it before, but I suspect this would be ok.

Comment: What is "the old system"? Is there a corresponding [change entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146) is an example of a question closed that way. This appears to be the change entry: "2013-02-06: The auto inserted text for questions closed as duplicates has been changed to "This question already has an answer here:" followed by link to the other question and the number of answers it has. The text is no longer edited into the original question but rather displayed externally."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summarizing from the comments and my own research:

- If a question is opened and re-closed, it will use the new system. However, the "possible duplicate:" message will remain, because the old system worked by editing it into the actual source of the post. This needs to be removed in a separate edit (requires 2,000 reputation to do unilaterally).
- If you re-open the question as a dupehammer wielder, you can re-close it unilaterally as a new duplicate, **only if** you were **not** one of the voters for the original closure.

Thus, in the case of [Mutable Default Method Arguments In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039191), I went ahead and made the desired changes myself.

Related to the original, I also sought to re-close [Python class function default variables are class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838255) as a duplicate of [Why does using `arg=None` fix Python's mutable default argument issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676729/). I was involved the first time around (over ten years ago!), so rather than opening it and waiting for closure, I went directly to [the SOCVR chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to ask for help. Another dupehammer-wielder (thank you, Henry Ecker) came along and handled that question the same way as I handled the first.