# Trying to edit old merged post gives false error about the edit queue

Tags: bug, edits, locked-posts, merged-questions

I had it in mind to go through [old Python questions that were closed under the old duplicate system](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=duplicate%3ayes%20%22Possible%20Duplicate%3a%22%20is%3aq%20python%20score%3a50..) to re-close them under the new system.

I found that a few rare old questions deemed "exact" duplicates under really old rules, got "merged" (I don't think this functionality is used any more, if it's even still supported). For example, [Python and the Singleton Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558).

The UI doesn't offer options to either delete or reopen the post (my MO so far has been to [open, hammer again and edit away the old banner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418439)), so I thought perhaps I would just edit the question and remove the banner.

(I don't know if this is relevant to the issue; but the question it was merged with, [Is there a simple, elegant way to define singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875), also later got closed as a duplicate. The canonical is now [Creating a singleton in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685) .)

When I click the Edit link, I get a message reading:

> There are [too many pending edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue) on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.

However, this message is erroneous. I am a 2k+ user, so my edits would not go into the queue anyway; and I am able to edit other questions at the same time.

Does the system consider old "merged" questions to be deleted and uneditable? If so, can I suppress them from searches somehow? (And then why do they appear by default?) I don't see any `merged:` option or similar in the search help.

Comment: "*I don't think this functionality is used any more, if it's even still supported*" mods can still merge questions closed as a dupe, but using this tool really needs care because it's not undoable. Also, [merged questions are locked automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hABbw.png). Regarding the erroneous error message, maybe there's a bug so that the system prioritizes "too many pending edits" checking to "this post is locked" checking?

Comment: But the system shouldn't be checking the edit queue for me at all AFAIK; and I reliably get the error on the same post (which I've been keeping open in a tab) at all times of day. The edit queue problem isn't *that* bad, is it?

Comment: I just tried again and got the same error message, proving my suspicion. And no, the edit queue problem is always that bad. The queue size is 500 items, and there are more users suggesting edits than at least 2 reviewers approving/rejecting the edits every time.

Comment: But why does it check the queue at all if we're over the rep threshold?

Comment: I guess that's an edge-case bug with locked posts (or possibly all situations where a user can't edit a post) and a full suggested edits queue, since among all SE sites, SO has a very high chance of reaching a full edit queue...

Comment: It makes me wonder if the system actually queues and then immediately dequeues the unilateral edit for some bizarre reason.

Comment: This is a known bug (searching for the initial report now). This will sometimes show when trying to edit any locked post instead of the correct "Post is locked" message (this is not specific to merge stubs).

Comment: For completeness: will `locked:0` exclude merged posts from searches, then?

Comment: The bug report in the now-linked duplicate was marked [status-review] ([last year](/revisions/350564/4)). It was being worked on around that time. There's also a report with merged questions on MSE [Attempting to edit a Merged question shows wrong error: "Suggested edit queue is full"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353839)

Comment: I missed the question about how to exclude these posts in your search. Yes, for the most part `locked:0` will only show unlocked posts. We do end up in a weird situation sometimes where answers that are indirectly locked (_e.g._ the historical lock) that will show the answers as not locked (locked:0), but cannot be interacted with because the _question_ holds a lock that affects them. There also shouldn't be any unlocked merge stubs.

Comment: I'm only interested in searching for questions, so I think that's good enough for my purposes.

Comment: I also removed the auto-inserted text since it's already linked in the merge header, so it'll stop showing up in your searches either way.